# Two questions regarding the net panel in Firebug

Tags: performance, firebug, analysis

can someone tell me two things about the net panel in firebug?

1. why is there a 'distance' between the first line and the following ones? what is happening there?
2. what is the exact meaning of the blue and red lines on the right side?

Any help is REALLY appreciated - thanks a lot in advance...

[alt text http://www.walkner.biz/_temp/firebug.png](http://www.walkner.biz/_temp/firebug.png)

Comment: What OS and FF browser version are you working with?

Comment: OS: Windows XP
FF version: 3.0.8
Firebug: 1.3.3b2

Comment: The large delay after the first row was probably due to an XHR request. Can you share the rest of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but my question is WHY the second item
>   didn't load until then... shouldn't it
>   start immediately? – swalkner

On my machine, it is nearly sequential. I would contribute the lag to cpu time required to process and render the data.

I would guess the blue line is when the browser starts displaying and the red line is when the layout finished.

Answer (score 5):

the blue and red lines mark when the javascript events (DOMContentLoaded and load) are fired.

mozdev-documentation for [DOMContentLoaded and load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events):

> Fired on a Window object when a document's DOM content is finished loading, but unlike "load", does not wait until all images are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

From the far left to the far right is the time of the total loading experience (1.03s).

The second item "?" didn't start loading until about 75% into the entire loading process.

Comment: but my question is WHY the second item didn't load until then... shouldn't it start immediately?

Comment: Can you show what items where being loaded on those first few lines?  That would help us determine the lag.

Comment: @Swalkner : I'm guessing that the second item is dependent on the first (e.g. the html is the first item and an img tag is the second). In that case, the gap is the time taken by the browser to parse the HTML and figure out that there's an img tag, after which it starts requesting for the img (the second item)